# Heading text displaying at the center instead of displaying in the statring line in asp.net application

Tags: css, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have an asp.net application having modal pop up which looks as below:

```
Type : some text
Description : some text
```

There is no problem with the above until the description has more than one line. The title "Description" will display in the center instead of showing in the starting line like below:

```
Type: some text

               sadfdfsdfgdgdgfgfgdfggdfgdfg
               sdfsdfertefefedfvdxcv 
Description :  ddfrdvxcvxcvxvx
               dfgfgdfgdfgdgdg
               dfdgdfgdfgdgdgfdg
```

The "Description" should actually display like this

```
Description : adrferrfdfsdfsd
              adsdasdsadasdasdas
              sdffsdfsdfsdfsd
              sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

How do I rectify this?

I tried with different CSS styles but none are working. Please give me a suggestion to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this css

```
    table tr td
{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

or `vertical-align:text-top;`